# xdebug only profile php process not php-fpm process

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, profile, fpm

`php info.php` can triger profiling and write profile file to /tmp/cachegrind.out.* like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 roofe www        344 Jul 11 12:04 /tmp/cachegrind.out.6723
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root      7172 Jul 11 12:06 /tmp/cachegrind.out.6808
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root      7178 Jul 11 12:06 /tmp/cachegrind.out.6819
```

`http://example.com/info.php` cannot triger profiling

here is the php info

```
which php
/usr/bin/php
ll /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 May 21 15:14 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/opt/remi/php73/bin/php
```

I also found all the php process can trig prifiling, while php-fpm not.
ps -aef | grep php

```
root       927   919  1 10:51 ?        00:00:50 /etc/opt/remi/php73/bin/php artisan horizon:supervisor ......
root       948   928  0 10:51 ?        00:00:17 /etc/opt/remi/php73/bin/php artisan horizon:work ........
root     28161     1  0 09:45 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/opt/remi/php73/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www      28162 28161  1 09:45 ?        00:01:32 php-fpm: pool www
```

php.ini

```
;[xdebug]
zend_extension=/etc/opt/remi/php73/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.collect_vars = On
xdebug.collect_return = On
xdebug.collect_params = On
xdebug.profiler_enable= On
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
```

and nginx conf

```
location  / {
    index   /../home/index.html;
    add_header  X-Location /;
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/dev/shm/php73-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: General thoughts: 1) Check the actual settings from `phpinfo()` via browser - maybe it uses different config file etc. (you are not using Apache where it's a common situation, but still) 2) Check for file permission issue (in a folder where those files meant to be created). No other ideas.

Comment: Check PrivateTmp in php-fpm unit file (which result in /tmp/being redirect in some sub directory)

Comment: Path to zend_extension seems very strange.....

Comment: @RemiCollet It's OK, when I install xdebug, it show me to add this path to config.

Comment: As you are using php73-php-fpm from my repo, you should also use php73-php-pecl-xdebug from there....  (/opt/remi/php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so and /etc/opt/remi/php73/php.d/15-xdebug.ini)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are affected by `PrivateTmp=true` in the service unit file:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/php72-php-fpm.service
```

By default XDebug store profiler file in `xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp`

You can either disable `PrivateTmp` or use a directory outside `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`